# I want to Add class 'your-active-class' to section when near top of viewport in JavaScript, but my code is not working

Tags: javascript

I have more than one section thats why i used for loop,
what can i do to add class to my section element?

```
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

function sectionInViewPort(element) {
    return (element.getBoundingClientRect().distance.top >= 0);
}

function AddActiveClass() {
    for (s = 0; s <= sections.length; s++) {
//if section is in view port add class "your-active class"
        if (sectionInViewPort(sections[s])) {
            sections[s].classList.add("your-active-class");
//else remove it
        }else {
            sections[s].classList.remove("your-active-class");
        }
    }
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', AddActiveClass);
```

Comment: Why are you looping if you only ever access `sections[0]`?

Comment: What calls these functions? Presumably there's a scroll listener somewhere, or are you just running this once on load?

Comment: I have more than one section in my html code.. and for sections[0] i updated it to be s

Comment: I think you have a typo. `s <= sections.length` should be `s < sections.length`

Comment: @Tala.sh you have many answers in your question. Please consider to up vote any of the  answers that are good for your problem, and also remember  to click the check-mark below the voting buttons for the answer that solved your problem. This reaction helps a lot the community :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few small problems but you're on the right track.

Firstly, try using `getBoundingClientRect().top` - which should give you a px distance from the top of the window to the item.

Second, you need to be calling your functions for them to work. You need to be calling `AddActiveClass` whenever the window is scrolled so it does it's checks whenever sections move up or down the page.

Third, you're grabbing all `section`s on the page but only using the first - i'm assuming this is just test code and you want to be checking all sections (in which case you'd use `sections[s]` in your code - the sections array using the looping `s` index.

finally, check your logic - your `top >= 0` check is going to add the class to every section below the top of the page - you might want to do something like `top > 0 && top < 100` to only hit sections near the top of the page, or add a check so that only one section ever gets the class added.

A rough idea of how your code should look, may need a couple tweaks:

```
// on window scroll
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {

  // get all sections on the page
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

  // loop through each section
  sections.forEach( section => {

    // get px distance from top
    const topDistance = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    // if the distance to the top is between 0-100px
    if (topDistance > 0 && topDistance < 100) {
      section.classList.add('your-active-class');

    // otherwise, remove the class
    } else {
      section.classList.remove('your-active-class');
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You had couple of mistakes in your code. Check the snippet, it should do the magic. And if you have any further questions, just ping me and I try to elaborate my code:

```js
const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');

const isInViewport = (section) => {
  const { top } = section.getBoundingClientRect();
 
  section.classList.toggle('active', top >= 0);
}

const toggleActiveClass = () => {
  sections.forEach(isInViewport);
}

document.addEventListener('scroll', toggleActiveClass);
```

```css
section {
  background-color: red;
  height: 200px;
}

section.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<section>#1</section>
<section>#2</section>
<section>#3</section>
<section>#4</section>
<section>#5</section>
<section>#6</section>
<section>#7</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my approach to your problem.

Of course you have remove the CSS I used for demonstration purposes, and also you have to remove the code I use inside the `AddActiveClass` I used for better understanding of what I did. The code to remove is the following:

```js
var span = section.querySelector('span');
span.innerText = distanceFromTop + ' - Greater Than Or Equal to O: ' + (distanceFromTop >= 0);
```

```js
function AddActiveClass() {
  const sections = document.querySelectorAll('section');
  
  sections.forEach(
    function(section) {
      var distanceFromTop = section.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      var span = section.querySelector('span');
      
      span.innerText = distanceFromTop + ' - Greater Than Or Equal to O: ' + (distanceFromTop >= 0);
      
      if( distanceFromTop >= 0) {
        section.classList.add("your-active-class");
      } else {
        section.classList.remove("your-active-class");
      }
    }
  );
}
document.addEventListener('scroll', AddActiveClass);
AddActiveClass();
```

```css
section {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

section:nth-child(1) {background :#0AF;}
section:nth-child(2) {background :#A0F;}
section:nth-child(3) {background :#AF0;}
section:nth-child(4) {background :#FA0;}
section:nth-child(5) {background :#F0A;}
section:nth-child(6) {background :#0FA;}

section span {
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #000000,-2px -2px 3px #FF0000,2px 2px 3px #00FF00,-2px 2px 3px #0000FF;
}

section.your-active-class {
  background: rgb(2,0,36);
  background: linear-gradient(41deg, rgba(2,0,36,1) 0%, rgba(9,9,121,1) 35%, rgba(0,212,255,1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<section><span>0</span></section>
<section><span>0</span></section>
<section><span>0</span></section>
<section><span>0</span></section>
<section><span>0</span></section>
<section><span>0</span></section>
```